# What is the difference between "גזרה רעה" "גזרה קשה"

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, language

Is there a difference between the concept of the Hebrew words of "גזרה רעה" an evil decree versus a  "גזרה קשה" a difficult decree?  See Machzor Rosh HaShana on the annulment of vows where it says: "וְכָל־מִינֵי גְזֵרוֹת **קָשׁוֹת וְרָעוֹת**" and אָבִֽינוּ מַלְכֵּֽנוּ בַּטֵּל מֵעָלֵֽינוּ כָּל **גְּזֵּרוֹת קָשׁוֹת**.

Also see Siddur Sefard, Yotzerot, Shabbat HaGadol: וְלָמָּה אֲכִילַת חָמֵץ ... לְהַעֲבִיר **גְּזֵרוֹת רָעוֹת**.

Comment: Are there particular places where you have seen one or the other phrase used?

Comment: In the Machzor for Rosh HaShana tefilot

Comment: Possibly because ra is distancing from God, as David Hamelekh says "As for my drawing close to God is what's good," whereas kashot are travails not necessarily distancing one from God.

Comment: Not sure if that makes sense since distancing from HaShem is what one initiates and does to God, no vice versa.

Comment: Artscroll quotes a Dover Meisharim that says harsh decrees are from Hashem, that although it’s for our ultimate good, there still extremely hard and tough to get through. (In essence, we are asking to be spared the decrees and get the benefit for free, my own add on). (Whereas, bad decrees are the ones from the government or king, this is my own addition)